# Flink resume from externalised checkpoint question

Tags: docker, apache-flink, amazon-ecs

I am using Flink running inside ECS installed from [docker-flink](https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-contrib/docker-flink). I have enabled externalized checkpoint to AWS S3 via `state.checkpoints.dir` to S3 in flink-conf.yaml.

Now according to Flink documentation [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/checkpoints.html#resuming-from-a-retained-checkpoint) if we want resume from a checkpoint in case of failure we have to say `bin/flink run -s :checkpointMetaDataPath [:runArgs]` but I use `FLINK_HOME/bin standalone-job.sh start-foreground`. So I am not able to figure out how my Flink job would resume from externalized checkpoint in case of failure.

Do we really need to have some config option option of resuming from checkpoint? Can't JM as part of restart strategy automatically read last offsets from state store? I am new to Flink.

Comment: Feedback: I've removed "hi" from some of your questions previously, because Stack Overflow is not a chatroom. There is a preference for technical writing here. With that in mind, I have also removed chatty material, trimmed some please-help-me pleading, fixed a spelling error, and added paragraphs.

Comment: Please have mercy on volunteer editors, by (a) using paragraph breaks (double Enter); (b) spell-checking your work; (c) refraining from pleading or writing tales of woe; (d) remembering that questions ideally are _permanent_ on Stack Overflow, and are intended to help many readers into the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The referred Dockerfile alone won't start a Flink job. It will only start a Flink session cluster which is able to execute Flink jobs. The next step is to use `bin/flink run` to submit a job. Once you have a job, which has enabled checkpointing via `StreamExecutionEnvironment.enableCheckpointing`, submitted and running it will create checkpoints to the configured location.

If you have [retaining of checkpoints enabled](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/checkpoints.html), then you can cancel the job and resume it from a checkpoint via `bin/flink run -s ...`.

#### Job cluster

In case that you are running a per job cluster where the image already contains the user code jars, then you can resume from a savepoint by starting the image with `--fromSavepoint <SAVEPOINT_PATH>` as a command line argument. Note that `<SAVEPOINT_PATH>` needs to be accessible from container running the job manager.

#### Update

In order to resume from a checkpoint when using `standalone-job.sh` you have to call

```
FLINK_HOME/bin/standalone-job.sh start-foreground --fromSavepoint <SAVEPOINT/CHECKPOINT_PATH>
```

Comment: I have configured checkpoints in flink-conf.yaml via docker-entrypoint.sh we start that and it seems like when we start container flink jobs runs not sure how they start without flink run and if no flink run how do I specify -S option.

Comment: Are you running a session cluster or a per job cluster where the Docker image already contains the job jars?

Comment: dedicated job cluster which runs single flink job

Comment: All right, I've updated my answer to also cover the per job mode.

Comment: I've responded to your updated question. In general, there is no good and recommended way to automatically restart the job from the last checkpoint because every job submission starts a new job context. Hence, you have to point the job to the checkpoint/savepoint you want it to restart from.

Comment: What if we have both savepoint and checkpoint configured? Can we use them simultaneously? If yes do we have to give -s option twice to read from checkpoint and savepoint dir respectively?

Comment: One can only specify one savepoint or checkpoint. You have to choose from which one you want to resume.

Comment: To enable checkpoint inside Flink job main method we call env.enableCheckpointing() is this the only way? cant we do it via flink-conf.yaml?

Comment: You can enable checkpointing from the `flink-conf.yaml` every 500ms if you set `execution.checkpointing.interval: 500ms`.

Comment: Also if we store checkpoints in S3, do we still need to explicitly say RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION in flink code or that too we can configure via flink-conf.yaml?

Comment: You can also configure this value in `flink-conf.yaml`. Please take a look at Flink's checkpointing configuration documentation: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/config.html#execution-checkpointing-externalized-checkpoint-retention.

Comment: How do I verify checkpointing works? When I cancel/kill Flink job it seem to again start from checkpoint 1 instead of last checkpoint n it created. How do we make sure Flink resumes from last checkpoint to avoid data loss. Please guide.

Comment: Checkpoints will only be used if the job failed and needs to restart. In the case of cancelling/killing a Flink job, Flink considers this a user operation and cleans up its state. If you want to resume the job after an explicit shutdown, please stop the job with a savepoint. Please take a look at Flink's documentation for further information: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/.

Comment: FLINK_HOME/bin/standalone-job.sh start-foreground --fromSavepoint /tmp/flink_checkpoints fails with error Cant find meta data file '_metadata' in directory /tmp/flink_checkpoints. Please try to load the checkpoint/savepoint from the metadata file instead of the directory. How do we give jobid at run time of failed job which contains checkpoints?

Comment: I guess that `/tmp/flink_checkpoints` does not contain the checkpoint/savepoint file you are looking for. Please make sure that the checkpoint is really contained in this directory before resuming `--fromSavepoint`.